# While loop inside a for loop not working

Tags: javascript

I tried to use a while loop inside a for loop, but everytime when I try do this my browser crashes. I know this happens when the loop is infinite, but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
for(i=0;i < 2; i++)
{
  console.log("hello");
  while(i < 2)
  {
    console.log("it's me");
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `i` is not changed inside the `while` loop, this loop will never stop.

Comment: When did you expect the `while` loop to stop? Did you mean `if`? Or what overall console output did you desire?

Comment: it is never going to stop as i will never be  greater than 2 in your loop and your browser will become unresponsive.

Comment: You need to change the "while" to an "if" and then perhaps it will do what you wanted...

Comment: Thanks guys, thought I could use the i from the for loop.

Comment: Please spend some time before posting in stack overflow, a simple while vs if understanding will help you solve this

Comment: @Deepak sorry, for some reason I thought I had to use an while statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the while loop, once `i` becomes 0, it will never come out of the while loop.(Since it is less than 2)

**Possible solutions:**

**SOLUTION 1**: Remove the **while** loop present inside the **for** loop

**SOLUTION 2**: Handle inside the while, and break after doing something

```
     for(i=0;i < 2; i++)
        {
          console.log("hello");
          while(i < 2)
          {
            console.log("i  < 2");
            break;
          }
        }
```

**SOLUTION 3:** Change the value of i >=2 inside the while loop, so that, the loop breaks

Comment: Thanks great explanation, haven't thought about the while loop being stuck so the i wont ++

Answer (score 3):

You loop the while loop forever, because `i` keeps the value and is never changed inside.

I think you might use better an if statement to get the additional output.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log("hello");
    if (i < 2) {
        console.log("it's me");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is your while loop is never ending; the value of i never changes inside the loop, so the loop continues forever.

Maybe what you were looking to do was log the message "it's me" when i, in the for loop, was < 2.  In that case, you can use a simple if statement, such that your code reads something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
 console.log("hello");
 if(i<2) console.log("it's me");
}
```

I'd recommend playing around with the number values and testing it out to get a better feel for how JS syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(i=0;i < 2; i++)
    {
      console.log("hello");
      while(i < 2)
      {
     //Once this block is entered, value of i is never changed and the condition
     //is always true.
        console.log("it's me");
      }
    }
```

Change it to something like the following using secon variable if you want to loop in the while section.

```
 for(i=0;i < 2; i++)
        {
          console.log("hello");
           j=0;
          while(j < 2)
          {
          j++;
            console.log("it's me");
          }
      }
```